# Laravel - Auth installed but logout route not found

Tags: php, laravel

I made a laravel system and included the Auth scaffolding stated in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/authentication). I installed it by using

```
composer require laravel/ui --dev

php artisan ui vue --auth
```

And running `npm install` and `npm run dev` to compile the assets. But for some weird reason the `/logout` route returns a 404. My routes look like this

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();
```

I don't know where to look. How can I fix this?

Comment: What do you get if you do `php artisan route:list` on the command line? `/logout` is a POST route in my installation, which means you cannot just browse to it in the browser.

Comment: It shows `/logout` in the list but whenever I make a link like `<a href="{{ route('logout') }}></a>` it just returns a 404

Comment: What does it show for the method for `/logout`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you take a look at `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php` you will see this piece of code:

```
public function auth(array $options = [])
{
    // Authentication Routes...
    $this->get('login', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
    $this->post('login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');
    $this->post('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout');
...
```

Which means that no `GET` route is defined for logout, only `POST`.
That's why you are getting a 404 response.
You can add one `GET` route by yourself with custom page, if you need, something like:

```
Route::get('/logout', function () {
    return view('my_logout_view');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The logout route is a POST request as stated by others. If you want to use it you

```html
 <a href="{{ route('logout') }}" onclick="event.preventDefault(); document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">Logout</a>

<form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" class="hidden">
{{ csrf_field() }}
</form>
```

Notice that the `method` in the form is set to `POST` and that we're using the `{{ csrf_field() }}` so we're allowed to make that request.